# Where is Cargo's certificate authority store?

Tags: ssl, rust, rust-cargo, certificate-authority

We are unable to use Cargo because our IT department intercepts all HTTPS traffic and replaces the certificates.  I need to add the corporate root CA to Cargo's list of trusted CAs.  Where is the file Cargo uses to store these?

Comment: Hopefully you are already aware of the giant security risk you are in. Does your company have a proxy? In that case, use [cargo ssl download error behind proxy on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47221811/155423) [Cargo on Windows behind a corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39220694/155423)

Comment: No it's not a proxy.  It's an interception appliance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started `strace cargo fetch` in a random project, and it looks like, on Linux at least, `cargo` is just using my system certificates:

```
 524 stat("/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem", 0x7ffccad52c70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 529 stat("/usr/local/share/cert.pem", 0x7ffccad52da0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 530 stat("/usr/local/share/certs.pem", 0x7ffccad52da0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 531 stat("/usr/local/share/certs/ca-certificates.crt", 0x7ffccad52da0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 532 stat("/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt", 0x7ffccad52da0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 533 stat("/usr/local/share/certs/ca-bundle.crt", 0x7ffccad52da0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 534 stat("/usr/local/share/CARootCertificates.pem", 0x7ffccad52da0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 535 stat("/usr/local/share/tls-ca-bundle.pem", 0x7ffccad52da0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 537 stat("/etc/ssl/cert.pem", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=220132, ...}) = 0
 571 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ssl/cert.pem", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

`/etc/ssl/cert.pem` contains many certificates, and one of them is good enough for `cargo` by default.

The registry is hosted by default on GitHub, which is ultimately signed by "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA" which is indeed contained in this file.

On some distributions (although I do not know how standard that is), you can add a certificate to the system store using the command:

```
# trust anchor your-cert.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an alternative CA store with the environment variable `CARGO_HTTP_CAINFO` or with the configuration variable `http.cainfo`

As in to set the CA for bash with an environmental variable:
`export CARGO_HTTP_CAINFO=/path/to/alterative.pem`